# Vuejs, computed property with setter freeze component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rich-text-editor, computed-properties, tiptap

I have a component with tiptap text editor. I use a computed property with a setter to bind data to the editor.

```html
<template>
  <tiptap model="editNoteContent" extensions" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    editNoteContent: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.Notes.currentNote.text;
      },
      set(text) {
        this.$store.commit("Notes/updateCurrentNoteText", text);
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

When I type a lot of text fast, my component freezes. I use a computed property because I have to get some current text, and only then change it. Does somebody know best practice for situation like this? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you can bring your text from store but don't commit to the store only if save or edit is pressed.

Comment: @YJRB, yes, it's kinda a way, but I try to achieve auto save solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution to this type of problem is to [debounce](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) the call, which delays the callback event. For example, you could debounce the mutation by using [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) to cancel any pending calls, and then [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to delay the `$store.commit()` call:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    editNoteContent: {
      get() { /*...*/ },
      set(text) {
        // cancel pending commits, if any
        clearTimeout(this._timer)

        // commit newest text after 300ms
        this._timer = setTimeout(() => {
          this.$store.commit("Notes/updateCurrentNoteText", text)
        }, 300)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it works like a charm! BTW, I thought about timer and probably will implement it today, but you answer is awesome =)